# Can not uninstall .NET framework 4.7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Unfortunately I have uninstalled .NET 4.5.2, I am using Windows 10 .NET 4.7.
My problem is that I need to Install .NET 4.5 for an application to work, but I need to uninstall .NET 4.7 first. Unfortunately the NetFxRepairTool does not support 4.7 yet. Is there any cmd line to uninstall 4.7 manually or any other way?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3186568/the-microsoft-net-framework-4-7-for-windows-10-version-1607-and-window. It shows the name and tools you can use to install (and probably uninstall) .NET 4.7.

Comment: I don't think you get a choice. .NET 4 versions are tied to windows 10 OS versions. E.g. Creators Update included 4.7, so if you're running that (or later) you can't roll back to an earlier .NET 4.x

Comment: *I need to uninstall .NET 4.7 first* Why?

Comment: While installing .NET 4.5 it saying ".NET Framework 4.5.2 or a later update is already installed on this computer.
" @Patrick Hofman

Comment: And why do you need to install 4.5.2 when 4.7 is an in-place update?

Comment: Rama, I see that "visual-studio" is one of the tags on this question. Is this an application you are developing and/or have the source code to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If an application's installer says it can't install because .NET 4.5 is not present, and you are on Windows 10:**

There is **nothing** a **customer** can do to fix this. This symptom means that the application's installer has wrong logic for detecting what version of .NET Framework is installed. .Net 4.7 **includes** .Net 4.5, so the installer is saying it can't work -- but it is wrong. This is a mistake by the developer who made the application; customer must obtain a fixed version from them.

FYI, This may happen for an older application that was made before Microsoft bundled .NET Framework with OS, changing how it needs to be detected.  [See this blog of a developer who encountered this in his own tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2013/11/11/fixing-a-net-framework-4-5-1-detection-logic-problem-on-windows-8-1/).

---

**If *you* are the developer**

then do one or more of these:

- Follow [these instructions for detecting .NET version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed).
- Make sure the .NET Framework version your project(s) target, matches the "prerequisite" in your "setup" project.
- Google "change launch condition for setup project", if when you "Build" your "setup" project, the Output shows a WARNING that mentions "launch condition". [On some VS versions: rt-click on your setup project / View / Launch Conditions]
- (If using an installer not included with Visual Studio) obtain an updated version of the installer you are using to package your product.